# Upload artifact (such as file) to git (bitbucket)

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

While creating pipeline through Jenkins,  I want my artifact(some txt file) to be uploaded to git. I tried giving remote repository name and file, log also shows that the file is being uploaded.
But there is no such update on git URL.
What am I missing here?

Comment: What plugin/function are you trying to use for this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then try to improve your question by editing it, focusing on a specific problem and giving details about it (code, configuration, error messages, exact problem your are facing.